# Getting back-end data and displaying it in the client

Tags: javascript, powershell, sharepoint-addin, web-services, rest

My SP Admin level is strong.  My SP dev level is beginner.  I know some JavaScript.

What is the best method of bringing Server and Farm information from the back-end to the client-side?  For example, what if I wanted to do something like show the farm version on a SharePoint page?  Or show the amount of memory on my web front-end server on a SharePoint page?

Is PowerShell possible here?  I've read some things about SOAP and REST, where the former is falling by the wayside.  Maybe Web services?

There's so much information out there and a lot of it is old.  I'd like to know where to start looking into this from a 2015 going forward stand-point.

Answer (score 0):

REST brings the advantage that it is client site and therefore O365 compatible.

Here is a small example how to get the items of a list with REST:

```
apiCallUrl = 'YOURSITE/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'YOURLISTNAME\')/items';  
console.log(apiCallUrl);

$.ajax({
    url: apiCallUrl,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },

    success: function(jsonData){
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.d.results.length; i++) {
            console.log('The ID of the current element is #' + jsonData.d.results[i].ID)
        }   
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("An error occured..." + data.responseText);
    }   
});
```